# Call a Controller in every 10 Seconds on CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron

I made research on site but couldn't find answer, so I decided yo ask this.

I'm getting data via XML and this XML renews every 10 seconds. So, I have to re-run my Controller in every 10 seconds. I can not make it via Cron as you know it is not allowing cron jobs under 1 minute.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: as you cannot use cron you can use javascript which will refresh your browser every 10 secs.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer but I don't want to open that page on my browser. System has to done it on background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use sleep and run the script once.

```
while(true) 
{
  sleep(10);
  // parse xml
}
```

Or if you wanna limit the time, then just change true with your limit and increment it in the end of the block. The only problem within this solution would be that if xml parsing takes 5 seconds, then this will be called in each 15 seconds, so make the arrangement according to this.

Comment: no problem, ne demek :)